# UK scones versus US scones

Tags: baking, flour

I remember listening to an America's Test Kitchen podcast where they compared UK v. US scone styles. They asserted that they were quite different from one another. And they seemed to favor the UK scone, their comments regarding a UK scone sounded alluring.

My question is, do you think there is a noticeable difference?

Comment: Hello Paulb, I'm afraid that requests for recipe recommendations are off topic here. Asking about the difference is OK though, so I removed that part instead of closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BBC is a good source for classic british food; here is [a classic buttermilk scone recipe](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/518627/buttermilk-scones) here, and [here is another made with milk.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/scones_1285) (I'd say buttermilk is the better way to make them.

The correct way to eat one is in a [cream tea](http://www.creamteasociety.co.uk/) - a pot of tea, a scone with tea, strawberry or raspberry jam, and clotted cream, served around 3 in the afternoon. Nothing much better in life ;) (Also, I had no idea there was a [Cream Tea Society](http://www.creamteasociety.co.uk/) until now.

As a Brit, I'm also a bit in the dark about US scones, but am I right in thinking it's a savoury thing -- I think the nearest British dish would be [beef cobbler.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/beef_cobbler_with_79871)

Comment: American scones are generally still quite sweet... often flavored with cinnamon or blueberries. We would call the topping on your beef cobbler example a "biscuit".

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I've heard the phrase 'biscuits and gravy,' so that heaven that isn't 'cookies in meat juices' :)

Comment: BTW, in the UK, there's a massive dispute over the name; usually southerners pronounce it 'SCOWN', and northerners 'SCONN.' What's the US way?

Comment: Yes, and the gravy used for biscuits and gravy is a cream-based sauce that often has bits of sausage in it.

Comment: In the US "scone" rhymes with "tone"...

Comment: "gravy is a cream-based sauce." I've been reading about it. Breakfast? Breakfast food? That's sounds somewhat unholy, I think ;) Sausage? Sure. Scones? Hmm. OK. But cream sauce in the morning?

Comment: The British scone can also be savoury, my local bakery has scones in plain, fruit (sultanas), cherry, cheese, wheaten, soda and potato.

Comment: I'm going to try the Beeb's recipe. I have a source for clotted cream. The golden caster sugar will be a challenge to find. I think I will put some turbinado sugar in the food processor and make it a bit more fine.

Comment: Here are typical US scone recipes, they are all over the board http://search.kingarthurflour.com/search?p=Q&asug=&af=type%3Arecipes&w=scones And I do see the irony in US scone recipes from King Arthur Flour :)

Comment: @Paulb Here's a note on substituting golden castor sugar in the US - http://www.nigella.com/kitchen-queries/view/Golden-Caster-Sugar/4380

Comment: You need to decide whether you are having the scones Cornish style - jam then cream or Devon style cream then jam.  It should be strawberry jam.  Blows have been struck over the order in which one builds a scone.

Comment: @user23614 is right. Is there a greater divide in British cooking that the Jam Firsters or the Cream Firsters? (Well, yes. It's the question 'do I put the milk in the cup before the tea?' But let's not open that can of worms ;) )

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this answers the question. Was it posted before the question was edited into its current form, or something? (Also, US scones are never savory, just the opposite.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the texture is very similar, but, as you might guess, I think American scones are a little sweeter.  There's another kind too...in Utah, people call fry bread (like a savory beignet) "scones". It drives me nuts. :)